# Oracle stored procedure failing when running on linux, works on windows

Tags: java, linux, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have procedure declared as:

```
 PROCEDURE procName(id in number, string1 in varchar2, string2 in varchar2, userId in number, updateAll in number, out_ret out varchar2);
```

When I'm trying to execute this procedure on windows or in SQL Developer it works flawlessly.
The problem comes, when running same jar on linux machine (centOs 7.1): oracle throws an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at 'foo', line 15
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'bar'
...
```

Here's the code:

```
public static Boolean callTest(long id, String string1,
 String string2, long   employeeId) {
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    Boolean ret = true;
    try {
        conn = getDBConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        callableStatement = conn.prepareCall("{ CALL proc_name(?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
        callableStatement.setLong(1, id);
        callableStatement.setString(2, string1);
        callableStatement.setString(3, string2);
        callableStatement.setLong(4, employeeId);
        callableStatement.setBoolean(5, true);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(6, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.execute();
        String out = callableStatement.getString(6);
        log.info("Procedure returned:" + out);
        conn.rollback();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.info("Procedure exception:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        if (callableStatement != null) {
            try {
                callableStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.info("Error trying to close statement:" +     e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                log.info("Error trying to close connection:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;

}

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy");
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,
                DB_PASSWORD);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        log.info("error creating connection" + e.getLocalizedMessage());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.info("error creating connection" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return dbConnection;
}
```

The parameters of the call are the same.

What is the cause of this issue ?

**@Edit 1**
Jar is created on windows, and then run on windows and linux, so DB url, user and password are the same for both systems.


**@Edit 2**
I can't give any procedure, or trigger code, i don't have it.

Comment: The error you are getting indicates the select you are performing returns no rows, it is very unlikely this stems from the difference in operating systems. More likely you are accessing different databases on each environment, and that the data in the tables is not the same.

Comment: Can you add the code for trigger 'bar' just in case that is doing something based on the client environment, as unlikely as that seems? (I could imagine a history trigger getting the current osuser and looking that up somewhere, for example; so a different OS account might cause an error. But pure speculation!)

Comment: Well the exception is being thrown by the trigger, so you'll need to ask someone who can see that code (assuming you can't see it in `all_sources`). We can't really help with things we can't see *8-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @[AlexPoole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole),
 Your speculation was right, 
Procedure was taking client user name,
 and looking for it in database.
Unfortunately system user was not the same on windows and linux.